# Fetching gitlab repo list : says "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: go, oauth, gitlab

I am trying to get repo list from gitlab using OAuth token.

My code looks something like this ... ("github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab")

```
    repositories := []string{}
    client, _ := gitlab.NewClient(gitRepoRequest.Token, gitlab.WithBaseURL("https://gitlab.com/api/v4"))
    fmt.Println("client...", client.ContainerRegistry)

    projects, _, projectListErr := client.Projects.ListProjects(&gitlab.ListProjectsOptions{})
    for _, project := range projects {
        fmt.Println("ID===", project.ID)
        fmt.Println("NAME===", project.Name)
    }

    if projectListErr != nil {
        // return err
    }
```

I am not able to get the project list.. the "projectListErr" says ...
`GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects: 401 {message: 401 Unauthorized}`

I am confident about the token value because I am getting list of all branches for a repo using the same token, that code looks like ... ("github.com/go-git/go-git/v5")

```
rem := git.NewRemote(gitMemory.NewStorage(), &gitConfig.RemoteConfig{
    Name: "origin",
    URLs: []string{gitBranchesRequest.Repository},
})

refs, listErr := rem.List(&git.ListOptions{
    Auth: &gitHttp.BasicAuth{Username: gitUserName, Password: gitBranchesRequest.Token},
})
```

Does that mean there is an issue with the library that I am using ? `github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the [type of token you are using](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication).

For instance, a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) might very well give you access to the list of all branches for a repository (for that project).

But for using the `/projects` API, 401 means the authentication information is not valid or is missing.

So make sure to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), linked to a user, not a project.

---

The [OP Keval Bhogayata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8733427/keval-bhogayata) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532432/fetching-gitlab-repo-list-says-401-unauthorized/70534327#comment124692102_70534327):

> I have found the issue.
>
> The library I am using ("[`xanzy/go-gitlab`](https://github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab)"), has different client creation functions for different tokens.
>
> I have been using the function that supports personal access token.  Instead I was supposed to use "[`NewOAuthClient`](https://github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab/blob/6b7a57c9b824daef2fb76f662ee2d6cd32345c87/gitlab.go#L253-L255)" !
>
> ```golang
> // NewOAuthClient returns a new GitLab API client. To use API methods which
> // require authentication, provide a valid oauth token.
> func NewOAuthClient(token string, options ...ClientOptionFunc) (*Client, error)
> ```

Comment: I made a curl request to the same API with my current token...
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?access_token=<my_token>", this is giving me expected result successfully. Therefore, I think token type is not a blocker here.

Comment: I have found the issue.
The library I am using ("github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab"), has different client creation functions for different tokens. I have been using the function that supports personal access token. Instead I was supposed to use "NewOAuthClient" !

Comment: @KevalBhogayata Good catch, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with relevant links.